# Gradle change classifier during dependency resolution

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have a dependency to a special version of a jar identified by a classifier (e.g. clover). I can easily specify it as a dependency. Unfortunately all its dependencies specified in the pom are without classifier.

```
compile(group: 'ch.mypackage', name: 'projectWithTransitiveDeps', version: "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT", classifier: 'clover')
```

I would like to change the transitive dependencies to use a classifier as well, but there's setter on the object:

```
configurations {
    compile.resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'ch.mypackage') {
                details.useTarget group: details.requested.group, name: details.requested.name, version: details.requested.version, classifier: 'clover'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will fail with an exception because classifier is an unknown property.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencyResolveDetails.html#useTarget(java.lang.Object)) for `userTarget` says *This method can be used to change the dependency before it is resolved, e.g. change group, name or version (or all three of them).* which seems to imply there isn't support to override classifier.

Comment: moreover this [document](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/design-docs/dependency-substitution.md#implementation) says `DependencyResolveDetails` is deprecated and you should use `DependencySubstitution` instead. Unsure what gradle version this affects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `userTarget` takes a string as well, can you try:

```
details.useTarget "$details.requested.group:$details.requested.name:$details.requested.version:clover"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work. There's no exception but it simply does not respect the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment in [gradle/gradle#8561](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8561#issuecomment-467456299):

> There is no interest in Gradle to leak the classifier concept to constraints, as constraints effectively apply to a module while the classifier is more of an artifact concept.

it is not possible.

But you can still [exclude transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps) and add your own, something like this:

```
ext.myPackageVersion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
ext.myPackageClassifier = 'clover'

dependencies {
  compile(group: 'ch.mypackage', name: 'projectWithTransitiveDeps', version: myPackageVersion, classifier: myPackageClassifier) {
    exclude group: "ch.mypackage", module:'transitiveDep'
  }
  compile(group: 'ch.mypackage', name: 'transitiveDep', version: myPackageVersion, classifier: myPackageClassifier)
}
```

See also [Gradle changing dependencies by classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230989/gradle-changing-dependencies-by-classifier). There was the same underlying problem